# How to scrape Investing.com Live Price Quote by importdata function (CSV) into Google Sheet?

Tags: xml, csv, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

Context: I need realtime future quotes of SP 500 to display on my googlesheet, since googlefinance doesnt provide quote for futures, I have been attempting to scrape the SP500 live and historical future quotes from 
https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-historical-data into my google sheet by combining the importdata function.

The problem is that I got to get the exact address of the .CSV file for the importdata function to work. To download the .CSV file from the site, I need to press the "Download Data" button",  but I cant pinpoint the valid link to the .CSV file through inspecting the button itself, by so doing, it only returns " javascript:void(0);".  In addition, I believe for the .CSV file to be generated, the request needs to include specification of the start and end date for the quotes, which makes it more difficult for me to figure out the format of the .CSV file link that I am seeking.

I shall be grateful if anyone would kindly help to suggest a solution or any workarounds that could get both real-time and historical SP500 future price quote in CSV format or by some other methods.

I have zero background in programming and am new to stackoverflow.com and am not  entirely familiar with its culture, my apology in advance if I have not provided enough information for my question or posted the question with inappropriate hashtags, I am happy to provide more details.

Thanks for your help and time, appreciate it!

edit(adding failed code/formula ):

```
=importdata("https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-historical-data", "javascript:void(0);" )
```

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: Sure, the formula I use is impordata ("https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-historical-data","https://www.investing.com/instruments/DownloadHistoricalData?curr_id=8839&smlID=500066&st_date=08%2F24%2F2017&end_date=09%2F23%2F2017&interval_sec=Daily&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC") and it returns an error.  Thank you!

Comment: Include the error message in your post.

Comment: "Error
Imported Xml content can not be parsed." The formula returns this error message. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `importdata`, try using `IMPORTHTML` in your spreadsheet as below -

`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-historical-data","table",1)`

It would import *this* table data from [Investing.com](https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures-historical-data) -

[image: investing.com]

...in the following format on the spreadsheet -

[image: spreadsheet]

Hope this helps!